# Symfony: Access $_POST variable from service without going scope request

Tags: php, symfony, service

I need to access a $_POST variable from a service and I don't want to pass `request` as a paramter as I think this forces me to use `scope: request` in the service and I have bad memories from this scope from the past, as this forces a service instance per request, instead of one instance per application.

The thing is that $_POST works all right, but as symfony best practices recommends to avoid using php primitives I ask if there's a better way to do it (avoiding `scope: request` in service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2.4+ you can use the `request_stack`, see [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).

You would use it like..

<kbd>services.yml</kbd>

```
your.service:
    class: FQCN\To\Your\Service
    arguments:
        - @request_stack
```

<kbd>FQCN\To\Your\Service</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class Service
{
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function yourCall()
    {
        $param = $this->getRequest()->request->get('your-post-parameter');

        //...
    }

    /**
     * Get current request object
     *
     * @return Request
     */
    private function getRequest()
    {
        if (null === $this->request) {
            $this->request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        }

        return $this->request;
    }
}
```

Comment: nive, hadn't heard of this before!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with doing it like below which is what I did some time ago. You're not injecting whole Request.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function searchByGetAction(Request $request)
{
    //.......

    $results = $this->productSearchService->findWithSimpleArray(
        $request->query
    );

    //.......
}

public function searchByPostAction(Request $request)
{
    //.......

    $results = $this->productSearchService->findkWithNestedArray(
        json_decode($request->getContent(), true)
    );

    //.......
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public function findWithSimpleArray(ParameterBag $searchParameters)
{
    $name = $searchParameters->get('name');
    $surname = $searchParameters->get('surname');

    //.......
}

public function findWithNestedArray($searchParameters = [])
{
    $name = isset($searchParameters['name']) ? $searchParameters['name'] : null;
    $surname = isset($searchParameters['surname']) ? $searchParameters['surname'] : null;

    //.......
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't pass (or I don't know how to do it) new parameters to service method, only I can pass parameters via `__construct` specifying it in `services.yml`. The method is an overloaded version of `Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/SimpleAuthenticationProvider.php->authenticateToken()`

Comment: Normally you would create a service class and define it as a service in services.yml then access it in your controller to inject variables into it but since I don't know what your app looks like I cannot really tell you how to refactor it in order to achieve this solution. If you can pass variables only thru a `__construct` then I would say you have limitations in your app.